# Does hashing of bitcoin addresses cause collisions?

Tags: address, hash

There are 2^256 possible public keys.

We generate bitcoin addresses by hashing these public keys using SHA256 and then RIPEMD160.

Now, since 160 < 256 won't there necessarily be collisions - multiple public keys will have to map onto one bitcoin address?